# Getting Exception while reading file content using solr line entity processor

Tags: solr

I need to search inside the file contents for which I am using Solr Data Import Handler. The response should show the content line where the search word is appearing. So for processing line by line I am using Line Entity Processor. My data-config file is

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" name = "fds"/>
<document>
<entity name="filelist" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" fileName="sample.docx"
          rootEntity="false"   baseDir="C:\SampleDocuments" >
        <entity name="fileline" processor="LineEntityProcessor"
                url="${filelist.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text">                   
                <field column="linecontent" name="rawLine"/>
        </entity>
</entity>
</document>
```

The schema.xml is having entry or rawLine.

```
<field name="rawLine"  type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

But when I am running the command for full-import, its throwing an exception
DataImportHandlerException:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.FileInputStream cannot be cast to java.io.Reader

Please help me on this as I have spend few days on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BinFileDataSource](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_1/solr-dataimporthandler/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/BinFileDataSource.html) works with InputStream while [FileDataSource](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_1/solr-dataimporthandler/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/FileDataSource.html).
You can try using the FileDataSource instead to check for the Casting issue.

```
<dataSource type="FileDataSource" name = "fds"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Jayendra. When I made the above mentioned change, I am able to d a full-import. But even if there are only 3 lines in the document its creating around 52 documents and even if i am searching for a content thats already present in the document, the resonse id still 0. Please help me on this as I am not able to find much information on line entity processor.